Problema con ViewTransition en Angular
Soy nuevo aquí y ya no se a que mas acudir para solucionar mi problema.
Tengo dos componentes, uno de inicio que carga libros con sus imágenes de la base de datos y el otro detalles libro que carga los datos del libro que he pulsado en el inicio.
El caso es que quiero una transición usando viewtransition de la imagen del libro en inicio a la imagen en detalles pero no funciona. He probado de todo y me he asegurado que el style "view-transition-name" se aplica correctamente en los dos elementos y es único para cada pareja del libro inicio-detalles. De hecho lo he probado sacando del bucle una imagen por defecto y emparejandola con una igual en detalles y si funciona lo que me trastoca aún más de porqué con las demás no.
HTML de inicio:
<div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
    <div style="margin: auto; margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px;">
        <form [formGroup]="filtrarLibrosForm">
            <div style="display: inline-block;margin-right: 30px; width: auto;">
                <select (change)="onSelectChangeCategoria($event)" formControlName="categoria" class="form-select">
                    <option value="" disabled selected style="font-weight: bold">Categoría</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let categoria of categorias" value="{{categoria}}">{{categoria}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline-block;margin-right: 30px;width: auto;">
                <select (change)="onSelectChangeAutor($event)" formControlName="autor" class="form-select">
                    <option value="" disabled selected style="font-weight: bold">Autor</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let autor of autores" value="{{autor}}">{{autor}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline-block;margin-right: 30px;width: auto;">
                <select  (change)="onSelectChangeTitulo($event)" formControlName="titulo" class="form-select">
                    <option value="" disabled selected style="font-weight: bold">Título</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let titulo of titulos" value="{{titulo}}">{{titulo}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline-block;margin-right: 30px;width: auto;">
                <select (change)="onSelectChangePaginacion($event)" formControlName="paginacion" class="form-select">
                    <option value="" disabled selected style="font-weight: bold">Paginación</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="15">15</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline-block;margin-right: 30px;width: auto;">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="quitarFiltros()">Quitar filtros <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-filter" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M6 10.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5m-2-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5m-2-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h11a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5"/>
                  </svg></button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>  
    <div *ngIf="cargandoLibros" class="loader-container">
        <p>Cargando libros...</p>
        <div class="loader"></div>
      </div>
      <img id="imagenPorDefecto" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="160" height="220" alt="Imagen por defecto" [ngStyle]="{'view-transition-name': 'item1'}">
    <div class="row" *ngIf="!cargandoLibros">
        <div (click)="detallesLibro(libro.id_libro)" style="padding: 20px; cursor: pointer;" class="book-item col-lg-4" *ngFor="let libro of libros; let i = index">
            <img id="imagenLibro" *ngIf="libro.imagen !== null" [src]="'data:image/' + obtenerExtensionFromArray(libro.imagen) + ';base64,' + libro.imagen" width="160" height="220" alt="Imagen del libro" [style.view-transition-name]="'book'+libro.id_libro">
            <img id="imagenPorDefecto" *ngIf="libro.imagen === null" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="160" height="220" alt="Imagen por defecto">
            <h2>{{libro.titulo}}</h2>
            <p>{{libro.resumen}}</p>
            <p>{{libro.precio}}€</p>
        </div>   
    <div class="clearfix" *ngIf="(i + 1) % 3 === 0"></div>
</div>


HTML de detalles:
<h1 class="display-3">{{libro.titulo}}</h1>
<div class="container" style="margin: auto; width: 60%; display: flex;justify-content: center;margin-top: 30px;">
    <img id="imagenPorDefecto" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="160" height="220" alt="Imagen por defecto" [ngStyle]="{'view-transition-name': 'item1'}">
    <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;margin-right: 50px;">
        <img id="imagenLibro" *ngIf="libro.imagen !== null" [src]="'data:image/' + obtenerExtensionFromArray(libro.imagen) + ';base64,' + libro.imagen" width="300" height="400" alt="Imagen del libro" [style.view-transition-name]="'book'+libro.id_libro">
        <img id="imagenPorDefecto" *ngIf="libro.imagen === null" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="250" height="350" alt="Imagen por defecto">
    </div>
    
   
    <div style="flex: 1; padding-left: 20px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="categoria">Categoria</label>
            <p type="text" id="categoria">{{libro.categoria}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="autor">Autor</label>
            <p type="text" id="categoria">{{libro.autor}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="editorial">Editorial</label>
            <p type="text" id="categoria">{{libro.editorial}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="edicion">Edicion</label>
            <p type="text" id="categoria">{{libro.edicion}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="paginas">Páginas</label>
            <p type="text" id="categoria">{{libro.paginas}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="isbn">ISBN</label>
            <p type="text" id="categoria">{{libro.isbn}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <label for="resumen">Resumen</label>
            <div class="input-group">
            <p type="text" id="categoria">{{libro.resumen}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="precio">Precio</label>
            <p type="text" id="categoria">{{libro.precio}}€</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="puntuacion">Puntuación</label>
            <p type="text" id="categoria">{{libro.puntuacion}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="mb-4"> 
        <div style="display: flex;justify-content: center;" *ngIf="userLogin && role == 'user'">
            <button (click)="favoritos()" style="margin-right: 10px;display: flex;align-items: center;" class="btn btn-warning btn-block" >Favoritos
                <svg *ngIf="!libroEnFavoritos" style="margin-left: 5px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-star" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M2.866 14.85c-.078.444.36.791.746.593l4.39-2.256 4.389 2.256c.386.198.824-.149.746-.592l-.83-4.73 3.522-3.356c.33-.314.16-.888-.282-.95l-4.898-.696L8.465.792a.513.513 0 0 0-.927 0L5.354 5.12l-4.898.696c-.441.062-.612.636-.283.95l3.523 3.356-.83 4.73zm4.905-2.767-3.686 1.894.694-3.957a.56.56 0 0 0-.163-.505L1.71 6.745l4.052-.576a.53.53 0 0 0 .393-.288L8 2.223l1.847 3.658a.53.53 0 0 0 .393.288l4.052.575-2.906 2.77a.56.56 0 0 0-.163.506l.694 3.957-3.686-1.894a.5.5 0 0 0-.461 0z"/>
                </svg>

                <svg *ngIf="libroEnFavoritos" style="margin-left: 5px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z"/>
                </svg>
            </button>
            <button style="display: flex;align-items: center;" class="btn btn-success btn-block" (click)="alCarrito()">Añadir al carrito
                <svg style="margin-left: 5px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cart4" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M0 2.5A.5.5 0 0 1 .5 2H2a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.379L2.89 4H14.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.621l-1.5 6A.5.5 0 0 1 13 11H4a.5.5 0 0 1-.485-.379L1.61 3H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5M3.14 5l.5 2H5V5zM6 5v2h2V5zm3 0v2h2V5zm3 0v2h1.36l.5-2zm1.11 3H12v2h.61zM11 8H9v2h2zM8 8H6v2h2zM5 8H3.89l.5 2H5zm0 5a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2m-2 1a2 2 0 1 1 4 0 2 2 0 0 1-4 0m9-1a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2m-2 1a2 2 0 1 1 4 0 2 2 0 0 1-4 0"/>
                </svg></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


Componente inicio
Componente detalles
He probado a sacar la imagen con una por defecto y funciona pero con las imagenes que quiero no
